# Can't use MaterialTextView

Tags: android, textview, material-design, material-components-android, material-components

I'm using Material Components but unfortunately, I can't use MaterialTextView. I don't know what I'm missing.

In my `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

And in styles.xml:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light" />
```

I defined my TextView like this:

```
<MaterialTextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

When I tried to launch the app, I get this error: `didn't find class android.view.MaterialTextView.`

So I tried to specify by using the package name `com.google.android.material` but in the autocomplete result textview doesn't appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MaterialTextView` is still in alpha state its *not* available in `1.0.0`. To use it you should

**Upgrade to the latest material dependency** :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong package `android.view.MaterialTextView`

Use:

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:layout_width=""
            .../>
```

Also it requires the version **1.1.0**, currently:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Comment: Nice. I am using with material alpha09 version